# Getting last inserted id from a table not part of the current controller I am in

Tags: yii

I need to get the last inserted ID from a table which is not part of the *current model* nor the *current database connection*: right now I am in table (pdtlisting) but I want to get the last inserted id from table (deallisting). How can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

Its for mySql..

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

**OR**

Its for Php..

```
mysql_insert_id()

All the last_insert_id functions (be they PHP wrappers or the native mySQL one) typically refer to the last ID created using the current database connection. The last login was probably not created during the same request you are showing the table in, so this method won't work for you.

Use a normal SELECT to find out the newest login instead - e.g. by using ORDER by creationtime DESC LIMIT 1.
```

**OR**
In Yii you can find the last inserted id like this ..

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

also you can refer this link..

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CActiveRecord#primaryKey-detail